# Only display data after search with datatables

Tags: laravel, search, datatables

I recently took over the development of a website that uses datatables. The site is built using Laravel 4.

I am new to datatables. I was wanting to know if it were possible to have the datatable load but not display any output/rows. The information would only show up once the user fills out the search bar.

I have gone over some of the available documentation on the datatables.net but haven’t found what I am looking for.

**EDIT:**
Here is a code snippet:

```
                table.dataTable({

                    // Internationalisation. For more info refer to http://datatables.net/manual/i18n
                    "language": {
                        "aria": {
                            "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                            "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
                        },
                        "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
                        "info": "Showing1 _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries1",
                        "infoEmpty": "No entries found",
                        "infoFiltered": "(filtered1 from _MAX_ total entries)",
                        "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
                        "search": "Search:",
                        "zeroRecords": "No matching records found"
                    },

                    // "bStateSave": true, // save datatable state(pagination, sort, etc) in cookie.

                    "columns": [{
                        "orderable": true
                    },{
                        "orderable": true
                    },{
                        "orderable": true
                    }, {
                        "orderable": false
                    }],
                    "lengthMenu": [
                        [5, 10, 20, 100, -1],
                        [5, 10, 20, 100, "All"] // change per page values here
                    ],
                    // set the initial value
                    "pageLength": 10,            
                    "pagingType": "bootstrap_full_number",
                    "language": {
                        "search": "Search Patient: ",
                        "lengthMenu": "  _MENU_ records",
                        "paginate": {
                            "previous":"Prev",
                            "next": "Next",
                            "last": "Last",
                            "first": "First"
                        }
                    },
                    "columnDefs": [{  // set default column settings
                        'orderable': false,
                        'targets': [0]
                    }, {
                        "searchable": false,
                        "targets": [1]
                    }, {  // set default column settings
                        'orderable': false,
                        "bVisible": false,
                        'targets': [4]
                    }],
                    "order": [
                        [4, "asc"]
                    ] // set 5th column as a default sort by asc
                });
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly possible and totally depends on your code. So please post what you have right now.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited my question to include a code snippet @Jerodev.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) example.

Let Laravel return an empty array by default so the table data is empty. It will call the ajax script on every "change" so once a user searches for anything, you can return the queried data.

More examples and docs can be found here: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/index.html

If you're using a package, you should also check the documentation for that version.